# Generate code from string parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, code-behind

I have class a called Template
In the class I have the method `Render(string)`;

I must send data to this method template, for example, I sent:

```
<% for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) { Console.WriteLine("*") } %>
```

Method Render get this string and write ***** on my cmd
I need to say, that I can declare local variables, cycles and other syntax of language C# in such way (  <% %>  )

Please, tell me, how can I do this?

Comment: you should show your tried code

Comment: I cannot get the problem clearly.

Comment: So, you are trying to create code which is compiled at run time?

Comment: i need generate code from string parameter :)

Comment: You can notify others by doing "@somename" instead of "Quote:somename"

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
private void Render(string words)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(words);
    }
}
```

Then in your form:

```
<% Render("hello, world") %>
```

Comment: what the console have to do with the web I do not know.

Comment: I just put `Console.WriteLine(words)` since in his question he has `Console.WriteLine("*")`, so I would take it up with the OP